# can you put two screen sizes in the same style?

Tags: css, button, styles, responsive

I want this button to be of different sizes, depending on the screen, is there a way to put two measurements inside the same style?

```
`<a class="btn btn-rounded" id="btn1" style=" margin-top: 10px; width: 384px; margin-left: 10px;"  href="<?php echo base_url('/newroute/nav/profissional/cadastrarcv'); ?>"> Editar/Atualizar </a>
```

`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it by `media query` in css.

for instance

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .btn-rounded {
    width: 30px
  }
}
```

this case detect that the screen is under 600px width and change it automatically